# Typescript: Create tuple from interface

Tags: typescript, tuples

Is it possible to generate a tuple type like `[string, date, number]` from an interface like `{a: string, b: date, c: number}`?

#### Scenario

I'm trying to add typings to a function where you can either pass an object, or the *values of the object's properties*, in order. (Don't @ me, I didn't write the code.)

```js
// This is valid
bookRepo.add({
  title: 'WTF',
  authors: ['Herb Caudill', 'Ryan Cavanaugh'],
  date: new Date('2019-04-04'),
  pages: 123,
})

// This is also valid
bookRepo.add([
  'WTF', // title
  ['Herb Caudill', 'Ryan Cavanaugh'], // authors
  new Date('2019-04-04'), // date
  123, // pages
])
```

So what I'm imagining is a way to generate a tuple that contains an interface's properties' types:

```js
interface Book {
  title: string
  authors: string | string[]
  date: Date
  pages: number
}

type BookTypesTuple = TupleFromInterface<T>
// BookTypesTuple =  [
//   string,
//   string | string[],
//   Date,
//   number
// ]
```

so I could do something like this:

```js
class Repo<T> {
  // ...
  add(item: T): UUID
  add(TupleFromInterface<T>): UUID
}
```

---

**Edit** The class does have an array property that defines the canonical order of fields. Something like this:

```js
const bookRepo = new Repo<Book>(['title', 'authors', 'date', 'pages'])
```

I'm authoring type definitions for the generic Repo, though, not for a specific implementation. So the type definitions don't know in advance what that list will contain.

Comment: Given that the types `{a: string; b: number}` and `{b: number; a: string}` are the same, I'm not sure what you expect to see here.

Comment: Somewhere in the code you're using it must assume that the keys come in a particular order; do you have access to that code? That is, you are essentially dependent both on `Book` as well as another type like `type PropertyOrder = ["title", "authors", "date", "pages"]`.  If you can get a hold of that type, you can make a  `TupleFromInterface<Book, PropertyOrder>` that works.

Comment: You're right, there is an array that establishes the canonical order of the properties. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @jcalz AFAIK, TS doesn't have a way to iterate through tuple/array type elements. So to impl this, it'll involve some crazily long and cumbersome overloads in order to make it generic. But yeah it is possible.

Comment: @jcalz sorry I misread your comment - the class contains that array at runtime, but the type definitions don't know how the class will be implemented.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the `Repo` constructor takes a tuple of property names, then that tuple type needs to be encoded in the type of `Repo` for the typing to work.  Something like this:

```
declare class Repo<T, K extends Array<keyof T>> { }
```

In this case, `K` is an array of keys of `T`, and the signature for `add()` can be built out of `T` and `K`, like this:

```
type Lookup<T, K> = K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never;
type TupleFromInterface<T, K extends Array<keyof T>> = { [I in keyof K]: Lookup<T, K[I]> }

declare class Repo<T, K extends Array<keyof T>> {
  add(item: T | TupleFromInterface<T, K>): UUID;
}
```

And you can verify that `TupleFromInterface` behaves as you want:

```
declare const bookRepo: Repo<Book, ["title", "authors", "date", "pages"]>;
bookRepo.add({ pages: 1, authors: "nobody", date: new Date(), title: "Pamphlet" }); // okay
bookRepo.add(["Pamplet", "nobody", new Date(), 1]); // okay
```

---

To be complete (and show some hairy issues), we should show how the constructor would be typed:

```
declare class Repo<T extends Record<K[number], any>, K extends Array<keyof T> | []> {
  constructor(keyOrder: K & (keyof T extends K[number] ? K : Exclude<keyof T, K[number]>[]));
  add(item: T | TupleFromInterface<T, K>): UUID;
}
```

There's a lot going on there.  First, `T` is constrained to `Record<K[number], any>` so that a rough value of `T` can be inferred from just `K`.  Then, the constraint for `K` is widened via a union with the empty tuple `[]`, which serves as a [hint](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27179) for the compiler to prefer tuple types for `K` instead of just array types.  Then, the constructor parameter is typed as an intersection of `K` with a [conditional type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types) which makes sure that `K` uses *all* of the keys of `T` and not just some of them.  Not all of that is necessary, but it helps catch some errors.

The big remaining issue is that `Repo<T, K>` needs two type parameters, and you'd like to manually specify `T` while leaving `K` to be inferred from the value passed to the constructor.  Unfortunately, TypeScript still lacks [partial type parameter inference](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242), so it will either try to infer *both* `T` and `K`, or require you to manually specify both `T` and `K`, or we have to be clever.

If you let the compiler infer both `T` and `K`, it infers something wider than `Book`:

```
// whoops, T is inferred is {title: any, date: any, pages: any, authors: any}
const bookRepoOops = new Repo(["title", "authors", "date", "pages"]);
```

As I said, you can't specify just one parameter:

```
// error, need 2 type arguments
const bookRepoError = new Repo<Book>(["title", "authors", "date", "pages"]);
```

You *can* specify both, but that is redundant because you still have to specify the parameter value:

```
// okay, but tuple type has to be spelled out
const bookRepoManual = new Repo<Book, ["title", "authors", "date", "pages"]>(
  ["title", "authors", "date", "pages"]
);
```

One way to circumvent this is to use [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) to split the constructor into two functions; one call for `T`, and the other for `K`:

```
// make a curried helper function to manually specify T and then infer K 
const RepoMakerCurried = <T>() =>
  <K extends Array<keyof T> | []>(
    k: K & (keyof T extends K[number] ? K : Exclude<keyof T, K[number]>[])
  ) => new Repo<T, K>(k);

const bookRepoCurried = RepoMakerCurried<Book>()(["title", "authors", "date", "pages"]);
```

Equivalently, you could make a helper function which accepts a dummy parameter of type `T` that is completely ignored but is used to infer both `T` and `K`:

```
// make a helper function with a dummy parameter of type T so both T and K are inferred
const RepoMakerDummy =
  <T, K extends Array<keyof T> | []>(
    t: T, k: K & (keyof T extends K[number] ? K : Exclude<keyof T, K[number]>[])
  ) => new Repo<T, K>(k);

// null! as Book is null at runtime but Book at compile time
const bookRepoDummy = RepoMakerDummy(null! as Book, ["title", "authors", "date", "pages"]);
```

You can use whichever of those last three solutions `bookRepoManual`, `bookRepoCurried`, `bookRepoDummy` bothers you the least.  Or you can give up on having `Repo` track the tuple-accepting variant of `add()`.

Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Wait what? I actually got the same result, a struct like `{ 0: SomeType ...}`, but does this qualify as a tuple? I didn't do the finally check, I thought it was some number-keyed object-ish thing. 

Comment: If you're using TS3.1 or higher, you should be able to [map tuples into other tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays).

Comment: I used the TS playground. My approach is basically identical to yours, it's just the way TS displayed the result lead me to believe I got wrong answer. Me first time seen a tuple displayed this way. Lesson learned. ^ Good source btw, thanks.

Comment: I can't reproduce that type of display on either the [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) or its [friends](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAMg9nA1gVzAHgCoBooGkB8UAvHlBAB7AQB2AJgM5SIQhwBmUGUA-JwNq4AulABcUahABuEAE4BuAFChInVABsIAMRlwAtgElqVGWwCGAYwiYcuMpRoMoAQRkzTINM1YcM+QiQBvKD59KABLaiYWdjxBMXgkVGs8EMFCAF8FCOMzSygAIQREKACFKChgMOANMXpgGQiAczKoU2RgAAs4GXpa+qaoAB8oOobqRr5BFtpTKjEAEVmIFrBTRohe8WRdACNZBUzlaAAlDeQ1YGJVMA1tPUMciytCpBw+ACJK6oh3nHe2zrdei-KDvGZUEHvVbrYFpBQAenhFXAJzOFyufFGTRwWPGQxG-XGkxwiyoOGo2z2MkEQA).  Looks like a regular tuple to me.  

Comment: @jcalz - this is an amazing answer, thanks so much.

Comment: @jcalz Is there a way to do the same but without specify the properties, just take all properties as a tuple?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to write util-like types in TS. However, for your use case it's impossible.

Key *order* doesn't matter in object-like interface, while it does in array-like interface. The information of *order* doesn't exist in the input, thus there's no way to derive such output out of nowhere.

---

**Edit 1: in response to OP's edit**: It seems there exists a solution at first sight, since all necessary information is given. However, due to limitation in TypeScript's type definition language, I cannot find a way to implement such util type `TupleFromInterface` that meets your need. So far the best result I can get is:

```js
type result = TupleFromInterface<Book, ['title', 'authors', 'date', 'pages']>
// yields:
type result = {
  0: string;
  1: string | string[];
  2: Date;
  3: number;
}
```

I cannot find a generic way to convert this `result` to the tuple we want. So close to success ! If anyone has any idea how to solve this puzzle, let me know!

---

**Edit 2: in response to @jcalz answer**:

This is my approach that produces the funny-looking misleading tuple display.

```
type ArrayKeys = keyof any[]
type Indices<T> = Exclude<keyof T, ArrayKeys>
type Lookup<T, K> = K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never;
type TupleFromInterface<T, K extends Array<keyof T>> = {
  [I in Indices<K>]: Lookup<T, K[I]>
}
```

Difference is I use `[I in Indices<K>]` instead of `[I in keyof K]`. Prior to the [change introduced in TS v3.1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays), `keyof Array<any>` also includes things like `"length" | "indexOf"`, that's why I use `Indices` to filter them out.

It turns out this approach is not only unnecessary in v3.1+, but also imperfect.

```
type TupleLike = { 0: number };
let foo: TupleLike;
foo = [1] // good
foo = [1, 'string'] // <- also accepted, not ideal
foo = ['string'] // bad
```

Conclusion, my approach is a legacy workaround, when using TS v3.1+, refer to @jcalz's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55522845/3617380).

Comment: I have a definition of `TupleFromInterface` in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55526906/2887218), in case you're interested.

Comment: @jcalz I updated my answer to show my original approach.