# Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type

Tags: typescript

I have created a interface in typescript and m trying to use it in a function but I am getting error.

Any idea why I see this error. Thanks...

**index.d.ts:**

```
export interface Test {
    TS: moment.Moment | Date | string;
    ID: string;
    QTY: number;
    PROD_DATE?: moment.Moment | Date | string | null;
    PROD_DATE_TO?: moment.Moment | Date | string | null;
    STATUS: number;
    ALLOC_QTY?: number | null | undefined;
}
```

**index.ts**

```
    const buildQuery = (row: Test): [string, Test[]] => {
            let query = `INSERT INTO TEST(TS, ID, QTY, PROD_DATE, PROD_DATE_TO, STATUS, ALLOC_QTY, INS_DATE) 
                         VALUES (CAST($1 AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE), $2, $3, 
                                 CAST($4 AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE), 
                                 CAST($5 AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE), $6, $7, now()); `;

            let insertUpdateValues = [
                moment(row.TS, "D-MMM-YY hh.mm.ss.SSSSSS A Z"), row.ID, row.QTY, 
                row.PROD_DATE ? moment(row.PROD_DATE, "D-MMM-YY hh.mm.ss.SSSSSS A Z"): null, 
                row.PROD_DATE_TO ? moment(row.PROD_DATE_TO , "D-MMM-YY hh.mm.ss.SSSSSS A Z"): null, 
                row.STATUS, row.ALLOC_QTY
                ];

                return [insertQuery, insertUpdateValues];
            }

const runQuery = () =>{
    const queryData = buildQuery();
    client.query(queryData[0], queryData[1]);
}
```

signature for `client.query` is `query(queryTextOrConfig: string | QueryConfig, values?: any[]): Promise<QueryResult>;`

**error**

```
let insertUpdateValues: (string | number | moment.Moment | null | undefined)[]
Type '(string | number | Moment | null | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'Test[]'.
  Type 'string | number | Moment | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Test'.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Test'.ts(2322)
```

Comment: `insertUpdateValues` should be an array of `Test` objects, but it isn't. Instead, it is an array of `string | number | Moment | null | undefined` objects.

Comment: if I do `insertUpdateValues: Test[] = [row.ENV...]` then i get error `(parameter) row: Test
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Test'.ts(2322)`

Comment: The `Test` interface defines the shape of an object with several keys: `TS`, `ID`, `QTY`, etc. For example: `{ TS: "someString", ID: "someString", QTY: 123 }`. What you are currently assigning to `insertUpdateValues` is not an array of those objects. That is what Typescript complains about.

Comment: so is it ok to make the function signature as `const buildQuery = (row: Test): [string, object] => {..}`

Comment: That works but would be suboptimal because you don't get the type checking. I've posted an answer about how to solve this with a tuple.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript: Create tuple from interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55522477/typescript-create-tuple-from-interface)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to define an array with fixed types for each entry, which is called a tuple. You can define this as a tuple as follows:

```
type Test = [
    moment.Moment | Date | string,
    string,
    number,
    moment.Moment | Date | string | null,
    moment.Moment | Date | string | null,
    number,
    number | null | undefined,
]

const buildQuery = (row: Test): [string, Test] => {
    // ...
}
```

That way you can return an array of values from your function. TypeScript will then check if each value matches the expected type at that index.

Comment: Thanks, I knew I can create tuple but I was trying to avoid creating interface & type for the same object... But seems like this is the only option.

Comment: Ah, you want to generate a tuple type from a given interface. This answer gives a solution you can probably use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55522477/typescript-create-tuple-from-interface. You will need to manually specify the order of the fields though, but the types will be taken from the interface.