# TypeScript: Type-safe way of converting between objects an tuples?

Tags: typescript, generics, type-safety

In a recent project, I have lots of classes that are essentially named tuples, and I frequently find myself needing to convert between those object and tuples. Which means, I basically have a lot of functions like this:

```js
const tupleToFoo = ([a, b, c]) => new Foo(a, b, c)
const fooToTuple = (foo) => [foo.a, foo.b, foo.c]
```

I probably should have just left it at that, but I couldn't help and wonder whether there is a more generic way to write this code. Here is what I came up with:

```js
type AnyConstructor<T> = { new (...args: any[]): T }

type KeysOf<T> = ReadonlyArray<keyof T>
type Lookup<T, K> = K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never
type UnionFromInterface<T, K extends KeysOf<T>> = T[K[number]]
type TupleFromInterface<T, K extends KeysOf<T>> = {
  [I in keyof K]: Lookup<T, K[I]>
}

function construct<T, K extends ReadonlyArray<keyof T>>(
  C: AnyConstructor<T>
): (t: UnionFromInterface<T, K>[]) => T {
  return t => new C(...t)
}

function deconstruct<T, K extends ReadonlyArray<keyof T>>(
  D: K
): (o: T) => UnionFromInterface<T, K>[] {
  return o => D.map(k => o[k])
}

function tupleToUnions<T, K extends ReadonlyArray<keyof T>>(
  t: TupleFromInterface<T, K>
): UnionFromInterface<T, K>[] {
  return t.map(i => i as UnionFromInterface<T, K>)
}

// This is particularly bad... :(
function unionsToTuple<T, K extends ReadonlyArray<keyof T>>(
  u: UnionFromInterface<T, K>[]
): TupleFromInterface<T, K> {
  return (u as unknown) as TupleFromInterface<T, K>
}

function instanceToTuple<T, K extends ReadonlyArray<keyof T>>(
  T: (o: T) => UnionFromInterface<T, K>[]
): (o: T) => TupleFromInterface<T, K> {
  return o => unionsToTuple(T(o))
}

function tupleToInstance<T, K extends ReadonlyArray<keyof T>>(
  O: (t: UnionFromInterface<T, K>[]) => T
): (t: TupleFromInterface<T, K>) => T {
  return t => O(tupleToUnions(t))
}
```

Which can be used as follows:

```js
class Person {
  static Keys = ['name', 'hobbies'] as const

  name: string
  hobbies?: string[]

  constructor(name: string, hobbies?: string[]) {
    this.name = name
    this.hobbies = hobbies
  }
}

const tupleToPerson = tupleToInstance(
  construct<Person, typeof Person.Keys>(Person)
)
const personToTuple = instanceToTuple(
  deconstruct<Person, typeof Person.Keys>(Person.Keys)
)

const p = new Person('John Doe', ['yodeling'])

const t = personToTuple(p)
const q = tupleToPerson(t)

console.log(p, t, q)
```

While that "works", the problem is that it is not at all type-safe. It feels like there should be a type-safe way of doing this, since all the necessary information is available at compile time. Hence, I was curious whether anybody knows a type-safe way to implement something like this?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/e8xvh8?file=index.ts) work any better for you in general?  If you like it I can write it up as an answer.  You'll never get *full* type safety for such a dramatic transformation, but you can keep the unsafe stuff inside your converter implementation and users don't have to deal with it.

Comment: @jcalz That's quite cool, thank you for the comment! Maybe it could work, let me play around with it for a bit. As an aside, I have to admit that working on this I took a fair bit of inspiration from your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55522477/typescript-create-tuple-from-interface